# How to access basecamp api in Codeigniter and where to define constant in mvc

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have tried code with core php its working fine:

*and where to include require statement in mvc.but while using Codeigniter nothing shown in browser 
source code of Codeigniter

```
require_once('../libraries/client.php');
require_once('../libraries/GrantType/IGrantType.php');
require_once('../libraries/GrantType/AuthorizationCode.php');
class abc extends CI_Controller
{

  function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('ea_model');
    $this->load->helper('url');
  }
  function index()
  {
    $data['abc']=$this->ea_model->ess_get();
    $this->load->view('e_view',$data);
  }
  function settoken()
  {
    const CLIENT_ID     = '******';
    const CLIENT_SECRET = '******';
    const REDIRECT_URI           = '*********';
    const AUTHORIZATION_ENDPOINT = 'https://launchpad.37signals.com/authorization/new';
    const TOKEN_ENDPOINT         = 'https://launchpad.37signals.com/authorizatio/token';
    $client = new OAuth2\Client(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET);
   $auth_url = $client->getAuthenticationUrl(AUTHORIZATION_ENDPOINT,REDIRECT_URI);      

   //predifined function of class client//
    redirect($auth_url);//used to redirect the url //   

  } 
}
2. here is my client class our main goal is to   create object  of class client  which used access  basecamp  api through oath wrapper class client in codeinator.

         namespace OAuth2;

  class Client
    {




      }
```

Comment: i have just included require in  abc.php   require('filename.php');

Comment: how to include in mvc   and where

Answer (score 0):

You should NOT use `require_once` the way you do outside your controller class. Instead use CI's load syntax in your controller method/constuctor:

```
function __construct() {  // if you only use the libraries in the settoken() method I'd
                          // recommend you to add them only there
  parent::__construct();
  $this->load->library('client');
  $this->load->library('GrantType/IGrantType');  
  $this->load->library('GrantType/AuthorizationCode');
  $this->load->model('ea_model');
  $this->load->helper('url');
}
```

Comment: how to resolve function settoken() code not executing  no thing happens

Comment: how to intialize object in codginetor .pls suggest  how to create object of client library code:                                       // $client = new OAuth2\Client(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET);

Comment: And the file libraries/client.php, does it contain a class named Client?